Read more button deactivates
The read more button deactivates when i make another one in another paragraph but as long as i make 2 or 3 read more button at the same paragraph it works. I want all the buttons activated how can i fix this problem ?


const parentContainer = document.querySelector('.read-more-container');
parentContainer.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const current = event.target;
  const isReadMoreBtn = current.className.includes('read-more-btn');
  if (!isReadMoreBtn) return;
  const currentText = event.target.parentNode.querySelector('.read-more-text');
  currentText.classList.toggle('read-more-text--show');
  current.textContent = current.textContent.includes('Read More') ? "Read Less..." : "Read More...";
})
<div class="read-more-container">
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, facere? Quae distinctio reprehenderit soluta fugiat, alias, doloremque similique tenetur magni voluptate a, perspiciatis quaerat! Necessitatibus velit consectetur expedita consequatur assumenda!
      <span class="read-more-text">
                                             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio quasi quaerat, amet explicabo magnam, nulla porro dolorem itaque
                                         </span>
    </p>
    <span class="read-more-btn">Read More...</span>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, facere? Quae distinctio reprehenderit soluta fugiat, alias, doloremque similique tenetur magni voluptate a, perspiciatis quaerat! Necessitatibus velit consectetur expedita consequatur assumenda!
      <span class="read-more-text">
                                             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio quasi quaerat, amet explicabo magnam, nulla porro dolorem itaque
                                         </span>
    </p>
    <span class="read-more-btn">Read More...</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card-courses-list admin-courses">
</div>
<div class="card-courses-full-dec">
  <div class="card-courses-title">
    <h4></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="card-courses-list-bx">
    <ul class="card-courses-view">
      <li class="card-courses-user">
        <div class="card-courses-user-pic">
        </div>
        <div class="card-courses-user-info">
          <h5>Client</h5>
          <h4>Khaled Ahmed Yasser</h4>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="card-courses-user-info">
        <h5>Request Date</h5>
        <h4>28/02/2024</h4>
      </li>
      <li class="card-courses-user-info">
        <h5>Total Meals</h5>
        <h4>15</h4>
      </li>
      <li class="card-courses-price">
        <del></del>
        <h5 class="text-primary"></h5>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="row card-courses-dec">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h6 class="m-b10">Request details</h6>
      <p>Start Date: 29/02/2024
        <div style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></div>
        <p>End Date: 15/03/2024 </p>
        <p>City: Nasr City</p>
        <p>Address: 8th district 9 Al zomor street </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <a href="#" class="btn gray outline radius-xl ">View Meals Details</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="read-more-container0">
    <div class="container">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, facere? Quae distinctio reprehenderit soluta fugiat, alias, doloremque similique tenetur magni voluptate a, perspiciatis quaerat! Necessitatibus velit consectetur expedita consequatur assumenda!
        <span class="read-more-text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio quasi quaerat, amet explicabo magnam, nulla porro dolorem itaque
                    </span>
      </p>
      <span class="read-more-btn">Read More...</span>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, facere? Quae distinctio reprehenderit soluta fugiat, alias, doloremque similique tenetur magni voluptate a, perspiciatis quaerat! Necessitatibus velit consectetur expedita consequatur assumenda!
        <span class="read-more-text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio quasi quaerat, amet explicabo magnam, nulla porro dolorem itaque
                    </span>
      </p>
      <span class="read-more-btn">Read More...</span>
    </div>
  </div>




You may be missing some important CSS in your example. If so, please update the question

They don't work because of a typo in your container class: <div class="read-more-container0">. Just remove the zero at the end. I suggest closing this as a simple typographical error

I removed the 0 in  but it didnot work

ok, can you tell me how can i update my question to add the css ?

There's a edit button right underneath your question.

That said, your other issue is document.querySelector('.read-more-container');. This only selects the first element with that class read-more-container. You need to use querySelectorAll to select them all and loop through each of them instead.

Here is your code where I've fixed the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/regts6vm/

yess it worked!

Thank you very much. should i ask whenever i add more "read more" button what should i change in code to make it work ?   I have copied your code and it works but i want to know if the document.querySelector('.read-more-container'); was my only fault ?

side note: instead of using current.className.includes('read-more-btn'); you could simply use the faster method: current.classList.contains
